# Syntax error when load csv file into mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

Compiler says the syntax error is near "FIELDS TERMINATED....."

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Data/books.csv' 
INTO TABLE Book 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@col1,@col2,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy) 
set Book_id=@col1,Title=@col2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: post a sample of you books.csv

Comment: Thank you, while David has solved the problem ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you have the column list and set before your fields clause. Mysql will have used the defaults when no fields|lines was encountered then processed the col list and then thrown an error when it encountered the fields clause. Try this

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Data/books.csv' 
INTO TABLE Book 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@col1,@col2,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy) 
set Book_id=@col1,Title=@col2
```